# Why is making a nested loop using a 2nd function faster than making it all in one function in rust?

Tags: loops, optimization, rust, nested-loops, primes

I am trying to learn rust, and as an exercise I am making a program that calculates all the prime numbers below certain number. Then, by accident, I found that making a loop within another loop is faster when the secondary loop is made inside another function and calling it, than when making it immediately inside of the loop. I do not understand why this can be, and I am hoping that you could explain me why this happens.

**The particular case**

Here is my little program:

```
//to get system time
use std::time::{SystemTime};
//to read the input
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("Welcome to the prime number calculation program. Please enter a number, and the quantity of prime numbers between 2 and that number will be calculated.");
    let mut target_input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut target_input).expect("Error: failed to read number!");
    let target: u64 = target_input.trim().parse().unwrap();
    println!("Calculating now prime numbers until {}.", target);
    println!("Using algorithm A.");
    let a = || {
        algo_a(target.clone())
    };
    println!("{} prime numbers found.", execute_with_timer(a));
    //algo B
    println!("Using algorithm B.");
    let b = || {algo_b(target.clone())};
    println!("{} prime numbers found.", execute_with_timer(b));
    //algo c
    println!("Using algorithm C.");
    let c = || {algo_c(target.clone())};
    println!("{} prime numbers found.", execute_with_timer(c));
}

fn execute_with_timer<F: Fn()->u64>(closure:F)-> u64 {
    let time_start = SystemTime::now();
    let result = closure();
    let time_end = SystemTime::now();
    let time_passed = time_end.duration_since(time_start).expect("Clock may have gone backwards");
    println!("{:?} passed.", time_passed);
    return result;
}

//algo b but without external function called 
fn algo_c(target:u64)->u64{
    let mut counter: u64 = 0;
    //collection of found numbers
    let mut found_primes: Vec<u64> = Vec::new();
    //check the range
    let mut is_prime_bool: bool;
    //inclusive range
    for i in 2u64..=target {
        is_prime_bool = true;
        for p in found_primes.iter() {
            //if i number can be divided by any previously found p prime, then it is not a prime
            if i % p == 0 {
                is_prime_bool = false
            }
        }
        if is_prime_bool {
            counter = counter + 1;
            //add to the list of found numbers
            found_primes.push(i);
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

//algo with register of already found primes
fn algo_b(target:u64)->u64 {
    let mut counter: u64 = 0;
    //collection of found numbers
    let mut found_primes: Vec<u64> = Vec::new();
    //check the range
    //inclusive range
    for i in 2u64..=target {
        if is_prime_reg(i, &found_primes) {
            counter = counter + 1;
            //add to the list of found numbers
            found_primes.push(i);
        }
    }
    return counter;
}

//function with register
//WARNING: This function will only work if used in an ordered way, in an loop increasing n+1
//a list of already found prime numbers must be supplied
fn is_prime_reg(number:u64, found_primes: &Vec<u64>)->bool{
    //first check dividing by the known primes
    for p in found_primes.iter() {
        if number % p == 0 {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

//the slowest algorithm
fn algo_a(target: u64)->u64{
    let mut counter: u64 = 0;
    //inclusive range
    for i in 2u64..=target {
        if is_prime_simplest(i) {
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
//Simple algorithm: the slowest traditional way of dividing by each lower number
fn is_prime_simplest(number: u64) -> bool{
    //try to find if it can make a exact division, if it can it is not prime.
    //exclusive range
    for i in 2u64..number {
        if number % i == 0 {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

One of the algorithms (algo_b) is optimized to check if a number is prime only dividing by the already found primes, instead of by all numbers. For this algorithm I made the second loop happen by calling another function. The detail is that, while trying to invent a better algorithm, I casually made another version of this algo_b that is basically the same mathematically, but in the program, the second loop happens within the first function. I called this "algo_c". Then, when I compiled the code and executed it, it happened that the algo_c is much slower than the algo_b, even though they do mathematically the same, and worse, actually algo_c is even slightly slower than algo_a, the brute force way to calculate the prime numbers.

**Times when using cargo run (test compilation):**

> Calculating now prime numbers until 100000.
>
> Using algorithm A.
> **5.447370201s passed.** 9592 prime numbers found.
>
> Using algorithm B.
> **1.091195151s passed.** 9592 prime numbers found.
>
> Using algorithm C.
> **12.764870792s passed.** 9592 prime numbers found.

**Times when using cargo build -r (release compilation with optimizations):**

> Calculating now prime numbers until 100000.
>
> Using algorithm A.
> **1.663481161s passed.** 9592 prime numbers found.
>
> Using algorithm B.
> **169.890757ms passed.** 9592 prime numbers found.
>
> Using algorithm C.
> **1.833567947s passed.** 9592 prime numbers found.

I do not get to understand how the algo_c can be the slowest one. Changing the number type from u64 to u32 or u16 did not change the fact that algo_c was always the slowest. I do not see why anything of this happens.

Why is this happening?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should NOT be using `SystemTime` for benchmarking. Use [`std::time::Instant`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/time/struct.Instant.html) instead.

Comment: Nitpick: Don't take `&Vec`. See [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your algo_c helper function you have this:

```
for p in found_primes.iter() {
    if number % p == 0 {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, the loop will end and the function will return as soon as the first prime is found that the number is divisible by.

In your algo_b you have this:

```
for p in found_primes.iter() {
    if i % p == 0 {
        is_prime_bool = false
    }
}
```

The loop will continue even after the first match is found, to iterate all the primes in `found_primes`.

To fix it, add `break` to exit the loop early:

```
for p in found_primes.iter() {
    if i % p == 0 {
        is_prime_bool = false;
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I made the correction and it indeed delivered comparable times, although still not the same, but with a little difference of 10% or less. I did not notice that the loop would go on there.